# How do you extend watercourses in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I dig out a channel to a lake, the lake's water only drains a few blocks into the channel where it comes to a halt.

How do I get a channel I dug to conduct water all the way to where I want it, such as a pond I dig out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good afternoon Pipsqweek!

Water has interesting mechanics in minecraft and it sadly means that digging a channel to a water source won't work as it would in real life. In the game water spreads to the next 7 blocks. There are two ways to extend it:

- You can deepen the channel on the way, the 8 block spread distance is reset every time the water "falls down" to a deeper level.
- You can use buckets to fill up the channel with water as Orgoss mentioned before. There is one important thing to keep in mind in this case: you don't have to fill every block with water along the way. If you fill every second block with water the block between them will be automatically turned into a full water block *"water source"* too. (This can be also used to create an infinite water source)

By the way infinte water sources: it is a great help to make one at your base, because it can help you out with many tasks (making a garden, etc). The easiest way to make one is to dig a 3x1x1 line somewhere and place a water blocks inside on the 2 sides, after that the middle block will be also transformed into a water block which you can take out with a bucket as much as you need.

Best wishes, I hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get some water with an iron bucket. Then you put the content of your bucket right next the previous block of water.

Try reading this page to understand water physics in the game.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water

Comment: Instead of placing it right next to the previous source, place it one block away, then refill the bucket from the block in between the two. Repeat. That way you can fill a long channel with 2 buckets of water.